# "Or" condition to get either ID value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating Booking engine for our project. Used jQuery & UI Datepicker

If user clicked return Trip, we need to get Depart & Return date. If User clicked One way trip, We need to get only Depart Date.

Getting date works fine as expected.

**My issue here:**

D_DATE_1 --> i need store value of  IDs 'returnTripDepart' or 'oneWayTripDepart' based on user clicked 'return' or 'oneway'

My logic works fine on return trip. When I select oneway, shows empty date value. Not sure how to use 'OR' logic for D_DATE_1.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="returnTrip">
    <input class="form-control" id="returnTripDepart" />
    <input class="form-control" id="returnTripReturn" />
</div>
<div class="oneWayTrip">
    <input class="form-control" id="oneWayTripDepart" />
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var maxLimitDate = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate() + 360, 0, 0, 0, 0);

$('#returnTripDepart').datepicker({
    minDate: today,
    dateFormat: 'd M yy',
    maxDate: maxLimitDate,
    numberOfMonths: 2
});

$('#returnTripReturn').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'd M yy',
    maxDate: maxLimitDate,
    numberOfMonths: 2
});

$('#oneWayTripDepart').datepicker({
    minDate: today,
    dateFormat: 'd M yy',
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
    maxDate: maxLimitDate,
    numberOfMonths: 2
});

function submitForm(){
    var $getDepartureDate = $('#returnTripDepart').val(), 
        $departureDate = moment($getDepartureDate).format('YYYYMMDDhhmm'), 
        $getReturnDate = $('#returnTripReturn').val(), 
        $returnDate = moment($getReturnDate).format('YYYYMMDDhhmm'), 
        $getOnewayDepartureDate = $('#oneWayTripDepart').val(), 
        $oneWayDepartureDate = moment($getOnewayDepartureDate).format('YYYYMMDDhhmm');

    var $getOnewayDepartureDate_1 = $('#oneWayTripDepart').val();
    var $departureDate_1 = moment($getOnewayDepartureDate_1).format('YYYYMMDDhhmm');
        if( !$getDepartureDate ) return;
        if ($('.trip-type--container li.oneWayTrip').hasClass('selected')) {
            $returnDate = '';
        }
        else {
            if (!$getReturnDate)
                return;
        }
    var $data = {
            ELEMENT_BY: 'D',
            D_DATE_1: ($departureDate == 'Invalid date' ? '' : $departureDate) || ($departureDate_1 == 'Invalid date' ? '' : $departureDate_1),
            D_DATE_2: ($returnDate == 'Invalid date' ? '' : $returnDate)
          }
     var $tripFlowUrl = $.param($data);
     alert($tripFlowUrl);
}
```

Comment: The user shouldn't ever choose both 'return' & 'oneway,' right? So why don't you just use the same variable to hold whichever value is needed? Then you won't have to worry about the portion of the logic you're struggling with anyway.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang :  Yes.. user have option to choose either way only. If 'Return Trip' selected, have to get '.returnTrip #returnTripDepart' date value.  If 'OneWay Trip' selected, have to get '.oneWayTrip #oneWayTripDepart' date value. This is the only logic required for now. Thanks